# How to convert SVG image to 32-bit RGBA with ImageMagick?

Tags: svg, imagemagick, rgba

How to convert SVG image to 32-bit RGBA with ImageMagick?

Background must be transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply try this command:

```
 convert  in.svg  -transparent white  out.png
```

(Assuming the original SVG uses a transparent or white background. Otherwise, if SVG background is red or blue or '#235689': use `-transparent red`, `-transparent blue` or `-transparent '#235689'`....)

If your version of ImageMagick doesn't do it right, check if `convert -list configure | grep svg` shows `rsvg` output in the `DELEGATES` and `CONFIGURE` lines.

Comment: Original svg uses transparent background. There are white areas on original svg. They become transparent. -transparent and -alpha options don't change anything. Tried to change #FFFFFF to #FEFEFE on original svg. No effect.

Comment: @alkedr: I do not understand what you mean. Is it that you want the white areas in the original SVG to stay white and not become transparent? Can you supply a (link to a) sample SVG which exhibits this behavior?

Comment: @alkedr: Does `convert http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/Chess_pll45.svg -transparent '#ffce9e' out.png` do for this example what you wanted? (At least the background color from the SVG, '#ffce9e' is now transformed to transparent in the PNG output.)

Comment: @Pfeifle: It doesn't delete background completely.
Found same image without background:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Chess_plt45.svg.
I need to convert to rgba, not png.
`convert http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Chess_plt45.svg -resize 64x64 -depth 8 out.rgba`
leaves white background (alpha = 0xFF).
`-transparent white`
doesn't work because not all white must become transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting background to *none* worked for me:

```
convert -background none in.svg out.png
```